# Invisible / transparent source of light. How to turn on?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting

Something happened and the light source is no longer visible to me, how to make it visible again? Light falls, but the source is not visible.

If you make an object and apply the emission shader - everything is visible. And standard lighting objects are not visible (spot, plane, etc)

I already tried creating a new file

[image]

Comment: So what are you showing? Is it not an area light? If your source lights are not visible, maybe you've turned off their visibility in the Object Type Visibility menu (header menu, with an eye icon)?

Comment: Hello :). [Point/Spot/Area/Sun Lamps](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html) *cannot* be made visible in renders. The only way to make a light source visible in a render is to use a Mesh Light with an emission shader.

Comment: @JachymMichal thanks, i cheked it. I accidentally was thinking that it must be visible)